# ERROR: Bitbake couldn't find CMakelists.txt after extraction (Yocto)

Tags: cmake, yocto

I am trying to compile Ceres solver on a yocto build (for Intel Aero drone).

I earlier tried pulling using the git repository at https://ceres-solver.googlesource.com/ceres-solver/ but could not get it to fetch. So I downloaded the tar.gz file myself, uploaded it on a public domain I own and tried to compile.

Here is how my bb file looks as of now.

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = ""

DEPENDS = "glog gcc libeigen"
SRC_URI = "http://sidj.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/ceres-solver-41455566ac633e55f222bce7c4d2cb4cc33d5c72.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6f24d5639bbe738e6f8ca5d7a129400e"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "005ed7405350767f22164d9fff93b3613207eeef9cbb56afbd02335542360b16"

PV = "1.0"

S = "${WORKDIR}/ceres-cmake"

inherit cmake pkgconfig

# Specify any options you want to pass to cmake using EXTRA_OECMAKE:
EXTRA_OECMAKE = ""
```

Now I see the download getting completed, but upon running the bitbake ceres command, I get an error saying that CMakelists.txt could not be found, while it is clearly in the tar.gz file. I looked at other recipes that seem to work, and feel that the do_unpack step is not the one failing. The output of the console is:

```
Loading cache...done.
Loaded 2790 entries from dependency cache.
Parsing recipes...done.
Parsing of 2225 .bb files complete (2219 cached, 6 parsed). 2794 targets, 109 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies

Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.30.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal"
TARGET_SYS        = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE           = "intel-aero"
DISTRO            = "poky-aero"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "1.4.0-dev"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m64 corei7"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    = "HEAD:cca8dd15c8096626052f6d8d25ff1e9a606104a3"
meta-qt4          = "HEAD:fc9b050569e94b5176bed28b69ef28514e4e4553"
meta-qt5          = "HEAD:9aa870eecf6dc7a87678393bd55b97e21033ab48"
meta-uav          = "HEAD:0f9395139b6a3c3f0f2c18a6a87f4048d0ca1a4f"
meta-ros          = "HEAD:4258013ec33f5ed2b0c9be12fb5902fe918fe98b"
meta-intel-realsense = "HEAD:82e9dbfd8783292f42f4a6fcc7bd5b8a6b1c567a"
meta-intel-aero   = "HEAD:1d7e341ff35aa903c37491f94677bdacc9427f6e"
meta-oe           
meta-python       
meta-networking   = "HEAD:55c8a76da5dc099a7bc3838495c672140cedb78e"
meta-cmu-rasl     = "master:39e39bf41e915323bf7cb70cad50e67cb8b1b90e"
meta-dense-visual-tracking = "HEAD:cca8dd15c8096626052f6d8d25ff1e9a606104a3"
meta-intel        = "HEAD:1f8dd1b00ce9c72d73583c405ec392690d9b08b7"

NOTE: Preparing RunQueue
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Running setscene task 184 of 202 (/home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_populate_lic_setscene)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_populate_lic_setscene: Started
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_populate_lic_setscene: Succeeded
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
NOTE: Running task 711 of 722 (ID: 4, /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_fetch)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_fetch: Started
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_fetch: Succeeded
NOTE: Running task 712 of 722 (ID: 0, /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_unpack)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_unpack: Started
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_unpack: Succeeded
NOTE: Running task 713 of 722 (ID: 1, /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_patch)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_patch: Started
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_patch: Succeeded
NOTE: Running task 714 of 722 (ID: 5, /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_generate_toolchain_file)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_generate_toolchain_file: Started
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_generate_toolchain_file: Succeeded
NOTE: Running task 716 of 722 (ID: 6, /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_configure)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_configure: Started
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function sysroot_cleansstate
| DEBUG: Python function sysroot_cleansstate finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| CMake Error: The source directory "/home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ceres/1.0-r0/ceres-cmake" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
| Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
| ERROR: Function failed: do_configure (log file is located at /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ceres/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_configure.9002)
NOTE: recipe ceres-1.0-r0: task do_configure: Failed
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 716 tasks of which 711 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/meta-dense-visual-tracking/recipes-dry/ceres/ceres.bb, do_configure
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Am I doing something stupid or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on this, but if you look in the folder:

> /home/thesidjway/rasl_ws/src/intel-aero/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/ceres/1.0-r0/ceres-cmake

and check if your cmake file is present in that folder. Yocto expects your cmake file to be present in ceres-cmake folder.